# Optimizing union query

Tags: sql, optimization, union

I have a query used for internal search engine that is real long to execute (about 3" or more).

How could I improve / optimize / "get it faster" it as I need to do the "union" of two queries ?

```
SELECT id, name, rank, 1 as SortKey FROM MyTable WHERE name LIKE 'test' 
UNION SELECT id, name, rank, 2 as SortKey FROM MyTable WHERE name LIKE '%test%' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SortKey > 0 THEN 0 
              WHEN rank > 0 THEN 1
              WHEN rank = 0 THEN 2
              ELSE 3 END, 
SortKey ASC, rank ASC LIMIT 0,12
```

Also, I have to do 2 searches in *MyTable* (about 250K lines).

1- I search for exact term : '*test*' in name column. This should be the first results in the whole query results.

2- Then, I search for larger term '*%test%*' in name column, without the result(s) of the first query.

I.e. :

```
Mytable
id  name       rank
1   Robert     3
2   Roberta    5
3   Mark       8
4   Sophia     12
5   Robertina  1
```

1- I do a search on '**Robert**' :

```
Mytable
id  name       rank
1   Robert     3
```

UNION 2- I do a search on '%**Robert**%' :

```
Mytable
id  name       rank
1   Robert     3
2   Roberta    5
5   Robertina  1
```

Final result :

```
Mytable
id  name       rank
1   Robert     3
5   Robertina  1
2   Roberta    5
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, there's no need to `union` the results.  You can accomplish the same results using conditional ordering:

```
SELECT id, name, rank
FROM MyTable 
WHERE name LIKE '%test%' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'test' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, rank ASC 
LIMIT 0,12
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/139b5/2)

---

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Mytable (id int,  name varchar(100),       rank int);

insert into Mytable values
(1,   'Robert',     3),
(2,   'Roberta',    5),
(3,   'Mark',       8),
(4,   'Sophia',     12),
(5,   'Robertina',  1);
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id, name, rank
FROM MyTable 
WHERE name LIKE '%Robert%' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'Robert' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, rank ASC 
LIMIT 0,12
```

**Results**:

```
| id |      name | rank |
|----|-----------|------|
|  1 |    Robert |    3 |
|  5 | Robertina |    1 |
|  2 |   Roberta |    5 |
```

Comment: Thanks sgedded. I try it on a minimalist PHP script with a time counter and your proposition get 1.652 sec against 0.628 sec for the UNION.